# How can I implement close button feature in selectize drop down?

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

I've started working on Angularjs recently. In my project I'm using `'selectize'` to populate drop downs. I want to include clear cross icon(X) in every available drop down. I have searched the official doc of `'selectize.js'` library but didn't found an appropriate plugin to do so. Although, there are some patches for that but they are not up to the mark.

I tried to search for other modules but didn't found any with such a built-in feature. I found below code which will show and populate drop down boxes.

```
<selectize class="every" ng-disabled="ngReadonly" config="myconfig" options="myOptions" ng-model="myModel"></selectize>
```

It would be really appreciated If it is possible to achieve it in existing code.

Could anyone Please let me know what should I do to accomplish the same with current library or with any other library?

Comment: This can't work with angularJS. You have to wrap Selectize in a directive, in order to run selectize before compiling the ng-options directive (or the repeat inside the select)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any library...

Assuming you have an array of strings

```
<select style="display: none" ng-model="myModel" ng-disabled="ngReadonly">
      <option ng-repeat="value for value in options" ng-value="value">
        {{value}}        
      </option>
 </select>
<ul class="my-select" 
     ng-class="{'show': showOpts}"
     ng-disabled="ngReadonly"
     ng-click="showOpts = !showOpts">
    <li ng-repeat="value for value in options"

          ng-click="myModel = value">
        {{value}}<span class="select-x" ng-click="yourClick()">X</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and then stylesheet

```
.my-select.show > li {
      display: block;
 }
.my-select > li {
     display: none;
     position: relative;
 }
.select-x {
     position: absolute;
     right: 5px;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px; /* Adjust depending on your style */
     line-height: 1;
}
```

**OR WITH LIBRARY**

https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/

this is a powerful directive that allows you to do anything.